# Как лучше определить std::conditional_t?

Tags: c++, шаблоны-с++

https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/conditional

Почему std::conditional_t определён как

```
template<bool B, class T, class F>
struct conditional { using type = T; };
 
template<class T, class F>
struct conditional<false, T, F> { using type = F; };

template< bool B, class T, class F >
using conditional_t = typename conditional<B,T,F>::type;
```

а не как:

```
template<bool B>
struct conditional {
    template<class T, class F> using f = T;
};

template<>
struct conditional<false> {
    template<class T, class F> using f = F;
};

template<bool B, class T, class F>
using conditional_t = typename conditional<B>::template f<T, F>;
```

, ведь последнее эффективней?

Comment: А прочему вы считаете, что последнее - эффективней?

Comment: @PavelMayorov потому что 1 специализация

Comment: Во-первых трейты традиционно имею интерфейс с вложенным `::type`. Во-вторых во втором способе инстанцируется по два шаблона. *"1 специализация"* - так и в первом одна

Comment: Во-первых потому что вариант с `_t` появился позднее чем оригинальный `std::conditional`. Во-вторых, уверены что это быстрее компилируется?

Comment: @HolyBlackCat
1) можно ведь оставить старый `conditional`, но сделать новый `conditional_t` 2) вот ссылка на сравнение времени билдов https://build-bench.com/b/cYb6nuFHYxce98MZBJ08z9UCANo

Comment: @karmik См. также [Я случайно создал две учётные записи, как их объединить?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/merging-accounts)

Comment: @karmik Я поменял код в classic и better и теперь ваш альтернативный вариант медленнее в 3 раза компилируется. https://build-bench.com/b/D1GwAR8QbXlXtN-3cf4w6-JpOfE Видимо это особенность этого хоста. Мерять миллисекунды сложно.